# R: Summary information only for positive numbers in a range

Tags: r

I have variable in a dataframe that contains values between -70 and 78. If I use the `summary()` function, I get a summary with all the numbers included (as expected). 
Is it possible to run `summary()` ONLY on the positive numbers (>0) within that variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

The code below works, assuming your data frame is called myData and the column you want to filter (to values >0) is called x.

```
summary(myData[myData$x>0,])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(666)
x <- data.frame(col1 = -70:78, col2 = rnorm(149))
summary(x[x$col1>0,])
#       col1            col2        
#  Min.   : 1.00   Min.   :-3.1488  
#  1st Qu.:20.25   1st Qu.:-0.8714  
#  Median :39.50   Median :-0.1058  
#  Mean   :39.50   Mean   :-0.1004  
#  3rd Qu.:58.75   3rd Qu.: 0.6716  
#  Max.   :78.00   Max.   : 2.5789  
summary(x)
#       col1          col2         
#  Min.   :-70   Min.   :-3.14879  
#  1st Qu.:-33   1st Qu.:-0.80252  
#  Median :  4   Median :-0.06594  
#  Mean   :  4   Mean   :-0.07041  
#  3rd Qu.: 41   3rd Qu.: 0.68296  
#  Max.   : 78   Max.   : 2.57892
```